# What makes UIView resized back to default when the UIScrollView containing it is scrolled?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I made a UIScrollView and it is scrolled horizontally.

Inside the UIScrollView, A UIView contains a UILabel to display a text and a UIButton to hide the view.

The width of the view changes as the text in label is changed by the user, while the button keeps its size.

What I want the UIView to do is to keep its size when the UIScrollView is scrolled to left and right. But the UIView goes back to its original size when scrolled.

The image below shows what the storyboard is set up; two rectangles are UIViews and UILabels in each have a text of "Label" by default. A letter X is a button. The horizontal area containing those two is UIScrollView.

[image]

The next one is the scene I run the app in simulator. I programmatically changed the borders of these UIViews. Those texts are selected from the menu I made, and the widths of UIViews are changed as the widths of UILabels change. Disregard why both labels have the same text; I didn't handled the second view. The case is the same even with only one UIView.

[image]

When I scroll the UIScrollView to right, the problem occurs. The widths of those UIViews go back to default as set in the storyboard.

[image]

Theh function below is called when the menu is selected. Sorry for these friggin weird variable names

```
//selectedTextPrim, selectedTextSecn: String()
//result1Text, result2Text: UILabel
//result1, result2: UIView
//result1XBtn, result2XBtn: UIButton
func processAddResult(){
    result1Text.text = selectedTextPrim + " > " + selectedTextSecn
    result1Text.sizeToFit()
    result1.frame.size.width = result1Text.frame.size.width + 24
    result1XBtn.frame.origin.x = result1Text.frame.maxX

    result2.frame.origin.x = result1.frame.maxX + 8

    result2Text.text = selectedTextPrim + " > " + selectedTextSecn
    result2Text.sizeToFit()
    result2.frame.size.width = result2Text.frame.size.width + 24
    result2XBtn.frame.origin.x = result2Text.frame.maxX
//        print("\(result1Text.frame.size.height)")
}
```

Does the code needs to be changed? Or is there any way to manage this by adding some code onto somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your views are positioned by auto layout constraints. You can set the frame directly (as you are doing), but the next time the system performs a layout pass, auto layout will reset the frames according to the constraints.

Many things can trigger a layout pass. One of them is changing the `bounds` of a view. The way a scroll view scrolls is by changing its own `bounds.origin`. So every time the scroll view scrolls, it triggers a layout pass. During these layout passes, any change you made directly to a view's `frame` is reset to the frame dictated by auto layout constraints.

In this case, it looks like you want each label to automatically size itself to fit its text. Auto layout can do this automatically. If you don't put any other constraints on a label's size, auto layout will use the label's `intrinsicContentSize`, which the label sets automatically each time you set the label's text.

Then you want each background rectangle to automatically surround a label. You can do this by constraining the edges of the rectangle to the edges of the label (plus constants to provide padding). Then auto layout will automatically make the rectangle's frame follow the label's frame.

If you do it all correctly, the **only** thing you have to change in your code is the text of the labels. Auto layout will take care of resizing and repositioning the labels and the background rectangles.

You should watch [“Taking Control of Auto Layout in Xcode 5” from WWDC 2013](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/406/).